# Content Security Policy script wont run, being blocked by errors

Tags: javascript, html, json

EDIT: This has been posted for a full day now. Hoping someone can lend their advice.

EDIT 2: STILL UNRESOLVED.

So I'm working on an independent project but the premise of the google chrome extension is basically on a button click, run a script. The script contains a link that must be opened so it can run, I cannot figure out how I can whitelist the link in the script to run. here is my manifest.json code.

```
{
"name": "mybotnotyourbot",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "stoptryingottakemybot",
"options_page": "options.html",
"permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],

"content_security_policy": "'default-src' 'self' 'https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop.js'",
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": false
},
"page_action":
{
  "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon":
    {
        "16": "images/get_started16.png",
        "32": "images/get_started32.png",
        "48": "images/get_started48.png",
        "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    }
},
"icons": {
  "16": "images/get_started16.png",
  "32": "images/get_started32.png",
  "48": "images/get_started48.png",
  "128": "images/get_started128.png"
},

"manifest_version": 2

}
```

mostly everything is right now are just being used as a template to outline the project, error codes I'm getting are these...

```
CSP directive 'script-src' must be specified (either explicitly, or implicitly via 'default-src') and must whitelist only secure resources.
CSP directive 'object-src' must be specified (either explicitly, or implicitly via 'default-src') and must whitelist only secure resources.
```

these errors aren't making sense as all the links I use contain https

```
Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

I'm sure that one is because of the https.

Again I'm very new at HTML and JSON please don't be harsh! Any insight would be greatly appreciated :)

ps: the script is written in js.